# Email sending error using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using this function to send email using my codeigniter project.

```
public function sendMail()
    {
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxx',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );

        $message = 'test message';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('waaanjula@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to('waaanjula@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Your Subject');
        $this->email->message($message);
        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo 'Email sent.';
        }
        else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }

    }
```

but it gives "Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14" can any one please advice on this

Answer (score 0):

I see that configuration is Ok, if you are sure about the email and password then it must be the new security strategy of Gmail, they block applications from using your account, in order to allow for this, [go to this page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=fr) and follow the instructions.

Comment: You welcome, you can mark your question as solved then ;) have a good day @AnjulaWeerasooriya.